# Firebase Log Number of Reads for Each User

Tags: logging, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-analytics

I have a DB with documents of each person who uses my platform. I want to store how many reads each person is costing me. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible in firebase analytics but you can do that programmatically easily:

```
//this function will reach out to a collection called usersUsage which has documents with IDs that are the users IDs. Then this function will increment a field called readCounts by incrementValue. 

const userRead = (userId, incrementValue) => {
  const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(incrementValue);
  db.collection("usersUsage").doc(userId).update({
    readCounts: increment
  })
}
```

This works for reading documents in this way:

```
db.collection('cities').get().forEach(doc => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
  const userID = USER_ID;
  const incrementvalue = 1;
  userRead(userID, incrementvalue)
});
```